# Importing .fbc, .ftmb files into Linux GRAMPS?

Tags: gedcom, gramps, family-tree-maker

Will Linux GRAMPS import .fbc and .ftmb files?

If not, is there a stand alone Linux utility that will convert .fbc and .ftmb to gedcom?

Comment: Do you actually have an .ftc file?  Or is it an .fbc file? See previous discussions at https://www.ancestry.co.uk/boards/topics.software.famtreemaker/6348.1/mb.ashx and https://www.ancestry.com.au/boards/thread.aspx?mv=tree&m=432&p=topics.software.general

Comment: .fbc (.ftc above is a typo).

Comment: I've edited to fix the question and title.  (The Ancestry links were mostly to show why I was asking for a clarification.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, anything that works on one OS in GRAMPs works on all OSes. None of the usage documentation differentiates based on which OS it's running on (at least that I've seen; I'm a Mac GRAMPS user).

According to the [GRAMPS 5.0 FAQ](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Gramps_5.0_Wiki_Manual_-_FAQ) entitled "[What Standards Does GRAMPS Support?](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Gramps_5.0_Wiki_Manual_-_FAQ#What_standards_does_Gramps_support.3F)", GRAMPS should be able to read Family Tree Maker files (personally, I'd probably try the .ftc file first).

If it doesn't work or doesn't work properly, I'd recommend contacting [MacKiev](https://www.mackiev.com/index.html) (the company that currently owns/produces Family Tree Maker) to inquire about converting to GEDCOM format without the full application, or requesting help on a [GRAMPS mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/gramps/mailman/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have yet to hear from MacKiev. Went ahead and installed sw. If accepted .ftmb (with errors), but balked on .fbc (.ftc above is a typo).

Comment: Thanks. Have yet to hear from MacKiev, so installed sw, which accepted .ftmb (with several errors) but balked on .fbc (.ftc above is a typo).

Comment: This is only GEDCOM files created by FTM, not .fbc files created by FTM.

Comment: "Gramps is tested to support the following flavors of **GEDCOM 5.5.1**, Brother's Keeper, Family Origins, **Family Tree Maker**, Ftree, GeneWeb, Legacy, Personal Ancestral File, Pro-Gen, Reunion, and Visual Genealogie.

Comment: @RonJohn Ah, yeah, my bad; I misread the FAQ.

Comment: I've done that before... :)

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to import a `*.ftmb` file into Gramps 4.2.8 for Linux and it didn't recognise the format.

Consequently, it appears that Linux Gramps is unable to import `*.ftmb` files?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I think it does answer the question.  The answer is no, it doesn't import ftmb files.  It's an incomplete answer and probably better suited to be a comment, but the poster doesn't have enough rep to add comments.